# Logging stack trace in log appender

Tags: java, logstash

I would like to log the exception stack trace in `stack-trace` field of [logstash](https://www.baeldung.com/java-application-logs-to-elastic-stack) log appender instead of being inside the `message` field

```
public void exceptionsCatcher(JoinPoint joinPoint, RuntimeException e) {
    ...
    log.error("exception  : {} ", e);

    ...
}
```

I searched throw [community](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44128855/19359114) and just found solution with `grok` to filter out stack-trace from message field, what i would like is to set it at stack-trace field in application level and not in `logstash` filter .

Comment: Welcome to SO, please consider to approve the question or comment otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need extra configuration to do so just use proper overloaded method of your log provider, for example

```
    public void exceptionsCatcher(JoinPoint joinPoint, RuntimeException e) {
    ...
    log.error("exception : {} " + " some message description perhaps {}",
            e.getLocalizedMessage(), e.getMessage(), e);
    ...
}
```

The third marker will ingest stack trace into `stack-trace` attribute, find more about other overloaded methods in [here](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html).